# Understanding LMDB, I have Three Questions

Tags: php, nosql, lmdb, key-pair

The below was an email I addressed to their mailing list. But I never got any response nor was my membership ever acknowledged. So I'm asking here.

## QUERY A:

On the LMDB site, it mentions: "*it has the read performance of a pure in-memory database while retaining the persistence of standard disk-based databases*".

From that sentence, it's not clear to me how it all works.

1. Does it save all data on-disk (file), but keeps a certain amount in memory? Or only on disk, which is what I want.
   I do not want to save data in RAM, but on SSD. Can anyone please explain to me about it.

## QUERY B:

I have TWO scenarios where I need a key/pair nosql layer:

1. to store any event happening within the system, example: user X clicked on button A..etc
   This will then be shown on his "log history" page.
2. I would like to save php session files, just like Redis does, to improve I/O performance.

So does LMDB fit the bill for both?
For the scenario #2, anyone have done this before or have some pointers where someone else already implemented it?

## QUERY C:

I am having issues porting the PHP wrapper to be compatible with the new PHP 7+ versions.

<s>My work is here: https://github.com/7php/phplmdb where I tried using SWIG to regenerate the `.c`, `.h` and `.php` files. [But seemingly SWIG is messing up things](https://twitter.com/SaraMG/status/953816552037642240).</s>
(UPD Jan 2020: I have deleted the above repo, because as of PHP v7.2, LMDB has been integrated in PHP DBA by default which is great news)

1. My question is, has anyone been able to work with a PHP wrapper compatible with PHP7+ ? If yes, please get in touch.

Comment: To answer first one: lmdb uses memory-mapped files. It stores data on disk and uses operating system's mechanism to access it as if it was in RAM. The benefit of this approach is that OS does a great job at this. Here is a [good read](https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/ArchitectNotes)

Comment: @ren
thank you very much. Your answer has really cleared down my confusion. The was in understanding what "memory-mapped files" were all about. Thank you very much for the pointers.

For anyone else, looking for more details, this is also helpful:

https://ayende.com/blog/162791/on-memory-mapped-files